# Automatically delete a row in google sheets 30 days after a field is populated

Tags: google-apps-script, time, delete-row

I'm looking to automatically delete a row from a google sheet automatically after 30 days from a particular field being populated.

I.E. An employee is leaving the company, in the row, i want to display that this employee is leaving and when they've returned their laptop. Once i populate the date in which the employee returned their laptop, the row can remain there for 30 days, then delete automatically.

| Name | Laptop |
| --- | --- |
| Michael Scott |  |

** Once i entered a date into the laptop column, 30 days later, i want the line deleted from the sheet.

Is this possible?

I am not a coder so i haven't tried anything within the app script as i am unsure how to build it. I've seen this done before with moving a row over to a new tab based on a certain word, so i believe this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Run the function every day on a time based trigger

```
function drowafter30days() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Laptop");//reset sheet name
  let [hA, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
  let idx = {};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => idx[h] = i);
  let dt = new Date();
  let b = 0;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let d = new Date(r[idx["Laptop"]])
    if (DiffInDays(d,dt) > 29) {
      sh.deleteRow(i + 2 - b++)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help! i should have mentioned the following:
1. when i populate the date, its going into column "i" 
2. it has a different column header "date of signature".  
3. tab name is "Dashboard".

i know i can change "Laptop" to dashboard, but I am unsure where to update for #1 & #2.